# Is there a way to apply theme on converted access 97 form?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I upgraded an access 97 application to access 2010

When I create a new form, there's like a master design that I can apply on every forms with 1 click. This feature doesn't work on my old forms (Nothing change).

[image]

I tried to start with a blank database and import everything. Now the forms are a bit better looking cause the button are rounded and the font is better but I still can't change the labels background with the master design.

The color is like hard coded in the properties for every labels. I can select them all and change it but I will have to do it for every forms. Is there a way I can use a master design with my old forms?

Thank you.

Comment: I remember you asked this a couple of days ago, what happened to the original question?

Comment: I thought that because it was a community wiki people didn't want to answer cause it doesn't give reputation.Also, I had no answer, so I deleted the older one and now I'm trying to remake my question so maybe it's more clear. I'm currently editing it. I don't know if it's tolerate to do this on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Yeah, you're free to delete questions if they don't attract any attention and re-post as required.  Out of interest, how many forms are we talking here that would need to be amended manually?  I only ask because I would have expected a 97 to 2010 conversion to oust more serious compatibility issues.

Comment: About 80 with the subforms. I did the conversion 2 months ago. It went well and I didn't have to do many things to make it works in 2010. Unfortunately, all the new features are added and the only thing left is the design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theme fore colors are applied to labels using the following properties:

```
ForeThemeColorIndex
ForeTint
ForeShade
```

As near as I can tell, when you import a form from a different database where themes were not applied, the ForeThemeColorIndex value will be set to -1 for some controls. This basically tells Access that these controls have a color that's "hard coded" (though not in VBA).

I'm thinking the only way to fix this problem is to use VBA to open each form in design view, loop through all of the form's controls, and if the control is a label control (or any other control you're having trouble with), apply your theme colors using the correct theme-related properties. Once you've set the control to use theme colors, changing or applying themes should work without a hitch.

Here's a list of these properties. This is not necessarily comprehensive. I just pulled this using a basic loop looking at properties for a label control. These properties are the same for textbox controls. This list is with theme colors applied successfully to my label control named lblLastName:

```
lblLastName: BackThemeColorIndex=1
lblLastName: BackTint=100
lblLastName: BackShade=100
lblLastName: BorderThemeColorIndex=0
lblLastName: BorderTint=50
lblLastName: BorderShade=100
lblLastName: ThemeFontIndex=1
lblLastName: ForeThemeColorIndex=0
lblLastName: ForeTint=75
lblLastName: ForeShade=100
lblLastName: GridlineThemeColorIndex=1
lblLastName: GridlineTint=100
lblLastName: GridlineShade=65
```

Here's a link to some of Microsoft's Documentation on this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195247.aspx

Comment: +1 This should be the best (and possibly the only) way due to the hard-coded properties

Comment: Thank you sir, you made my day. It works!! I just need to find out what controls I have to do this to make my forms look like a real access 2010 form. Also, is it normal that if I create a new label, the theme doesn't work on it?

Comment: It's a mystery to me where forms look for their default information when you create new controls. I half suspect these are properties that are not accessible.

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/change-default-properties-for-a-control-type-HP005187707.aspx I think it's here

Answer (score 1):

Try opening up the form in design mode, then hit ctrl-a to select all objects. Then from ribbon on the design tab simply click on the themes and choose a theme as your picture shows.

Keep in mind that the option will be disabled if you are using an mdb, so you will have to be using the newer accDB format for this option to be available.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. I'm using a accDB format and when I do your steps, nothing change. The buttons, labels and textbox look the same no matter what theme I use. Thank you

Answer (score -2):

One way around this is to add the (old) AutoFormat command to the Quick Access tool bar. While it doesn't add the Themes functionality to a form, it is a quick way to reformat forms in a fairly quick and consistent manner.

Comment: This should be a comment and cannot be considered as an answer.