# Change background-color of controls

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

This question is related to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124482/is-there-a-way-to-apply-theme-on-converted-access-97-form)

**Summary**: I had forms made with access 97 and the themes weren't working on them. Since, I changed the Theme properties for each controls, I can now apply themes on them.

It works well for the font. As you can see, the font changes with the themes like it's supposed to do with a form made in access 2010.

[image]
[image]

but I can't get the background color of the labels and command buttons to work like a real access 2010 form.

I changed the `backcolor` and the `BackThemeColorIndex` properties but the color stays the same when I change the theme. Is there another property that I missed?
[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841398.aspx) the MSDN list

Here the list of all the properties in my script.

```
myControl.HoverThemeColorIndex = 1
myControl.HoverTint = 100
myControl.HoverForeThemeColorIndex = 1
myControl.HoverForeTint = 100
myControl.HoverShade = 100

myControl.PressedForeThemeColorIndex = 1
myControl.PressedForeTint = 100
myControl.PressedShade = 100
myControl.PressedThemeColorIndex = 1
myControl.PressedTint = 100
myControl.UseTheme = 1 

myControl.ForeThemeColorIndex = 1
myControl.BackThemeColorIndex = 1
myControl.BackColor = RGB(250, 100, 100)
myControl.BackTint = 100
myControl.BackShade = 100

myControl.BorderThemeColorIndex = 0
myControl.BorderTint = 50
myControl.BorderShade = 100

myControl.ThemeFontIndex = 1
myControl.ForeThemeColorIndex = 0
myControl.ForeTint = 75
myControl.ForeShade = 100

myControl.GridlineThemeColorIndex = 1
myControl.GridlineTint = 100
myControl.GridlineShade = 65
```

Thank you

Comment: 80 with the subforms, I did try to paste to a new form and no luck. I'm gonna try right now to export to text. thank you

Comment: @remou I can't find how to import a form with a text file. It's always about data for tables, I don't see anything about forms.

Comment: It is undocumented `Application.SaveAsText acForm, frm.Name, "z:\docs\tmp.txt"` -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584182/find-record-with-id/12585748#12585748

Comment: Thank you. That's sad, I should have remembered. the link you posted is my question.. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I still have the same behaviors with the new form.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot think of anything else. Hopefully someone will have an idea.

Comment: No problem, you have helped me already on many questions. btw are you an access mvp? Cause I was thinking about submitting your name

Comment: No I am not, and thank you for thinking if me.

Comment: I don't know if there's a way you can gimme your details here. They need your email address and your name to contact you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18866/discussion-between-remou-and-marc)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Gradient property to 12

For example

```
myControl.Gradient = 12
```

Alternatively you can create a new form and insert the button then copy the button and paste it temporarily onto a different form, and use the format Painter to copy the properties across.